# MATLAB - Fixed point iteration

Tags: matlab, fixed-point-iteration

I'm trying to figure out how to create a function for fixed point iteration. But I have been stuck on this for a good hour now and I am finally caving in.

So what am I doing wrong?

I would suspect that I'm updating wrong, but I am not really sure.

All help would be greatly appriciated!

```
function fixedpointint(x1,iteration,g,TOL)
x2 = g(x1);
i = 0;
while i<iteration && abs(x1-x2)>TOL 
    x1 = x2;
    x2 = g(x1);
    i = i + 1;
end
end
```

I call the function with:

```
g = @(x)exp(-x)*2;
fixedpointint(0.3,1000,g,0.001)
```

When I remove the `i<iteration` test, the function works.  I do however not understand why omitting it would make it work?

Comment: I solved this by removing the iteration. I do however not understand why omitting it would make it work..?

Comment: What do you mean with "removing the iteration"? Did you remove the `while` loop? Or did you remove the test `i<iteration`?

Comment: This question would be better answerable if you include the code that you use to call this function (i.e. what `x1`, `iteration`, `g` and `TOL` do you provide?)

Comment: g=@(x)exp(-x)*2

   fixedpointint(0.3,g,0.001)

and I meant that I removed    i<iteration

Comment: I’ve edited this information to the question. You can >[edit]< your question at any time to improve it! We prefer the question to contain all relevant information, these comments are not necessary preserved.

Comment: Are you sure about the way you call the function? There are only 3 arguments, but the function needs 4!

Comment: @CrisLuengo you're right. I've made so many revisions to the original so it's hard to track.

It should say:

g=@(x)exp(-x)*2 fixedpointint(0.3,1000,g,0.001). Btw how do you highlight your commands in the comments section?

Comment: Comments use a reduced set of the markdown accepted for questions. The backtick character `\`` should be used around code to format it with a monospaced font.

Comment: What is your issue? You lack your output arguments, e.g. `[x2, i] = fixedpointint(x1,iteration,g,TOL)` and then your call converges: 
`val = 0.8530
i = 44`